# How to make a directory of python modules look like a package

Tags: python, python-module

I'm working with some legacy software structured as follows:

```
.../legacy_pkg1/python/module1.py
.../legacy_pkg1/python/module2.py
.../legacy_pkg1/python/module3.py

.../legacy_pkg2/python/module4.py
.../legacy_pkg2/python/module5.py
.../legacy_pkg2/python/module6.py
```

The maintainer's method for running this code involves setting `PYTHONPATH=.../legacy_pkg1/python:.../legacy_pkg2/python` and `import module1`, instance. As such, there's plenty of opportunities for naming conflicts, which I'd like to work around.

Possibly options involve setting up soft links as follows:

```
.../legacy/python/legacy_pkg1 => ../legacy_pkg1/python
.../legacy/python/legacy_pkg2 => ../legacy_pkg2/python
export PYTHONPATH=.../legacy/python
```

The problem is that inside `module1.py` the following kind of imports exist:

```
import module2
```

So without rewriting all the legacy code imports, I can't see a way to make this work.